# Android: Make TextInputLayout Read-Only

Tags: android, android-styles, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

How can I set a `TextInputLayout` to read only?

My code is as shown below:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/TextInputLayout_fromAddAbsenceBottomSheet_AbsenceTaken"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="Absence Taken"
        app:helperText="* Optional"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/TextInputLayout_fromAddAbsenceBottomSheet_AbsenceGiven"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/TextInputLayout_fromAddAbsenceBottomSheet_AbsenceGiven"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TextInputLayout_fromAddAbsenceBottomSheet_AbsenceGiven"
        style="@style/Widget.Unify.TextInputLayout">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/TextField_fromAddAbsenceBottomSheet_AbsenceTaken"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            style="@style/Widget.Unify.EditText"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I need to make the `TextInputLayout` read only NOT THE `EditText`.

I need to make it read only at the `TextInputLayout` level because I need to apply a style to it.

I've already tried `android:enabled="false"` in the `TextInputLayout` but it still lets me change the text.

Comment: What does it mean only for the TextInputLayout? It is not clear for me. Do you need something at style level?

Answer (score 2):

```
android:focusable="false" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

make the TextInputEditText focusable false by default in your xml file

Comment: Please read the question carefully, i said i need it in the TextInputLayout not in the EditText as i need to apply some styles to the TextInputLayout on state changes!

Answer (score 2):

The question is not clear.

To disable the `TextInputLayout` just use:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:enabled="false" 
        ..>
```

It works with the version 1.1.0 (currently `1.1.0-beta02`) and 1.2.0 (currently `1.2.0-alpha02`).
Result: enabled/disabled:

[image]
[image]

You can customize the box color using the `app:boxStrokeColor` and a selector.
Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:enabled="false" 
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/text_input_layout_stroke_color"
        ..>
```

where the selector is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="..." android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.87" android:color="..." android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="..." android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:color="..."/>
</selector>
```

where the color used in the disabled state is defined by `<item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="..." android:state_enabled="false"/>`.

Result: disabled with different boxStrokeColor.

[image]

If you want to customize the color of EditText you can use the `android:textColor` attribute:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:textColor="@color/..."
```

Result: disabled with different editext color.

[image]

Also in this case you can use a selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/..."/>
  <item android:color="@color/...."/>
</selector>
```